# Alternating series with a trigonometric term

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to verify whether 
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})}{k}$$
converges absolutely or conditionally but I don't know how to deal with the $\sin$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that $\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})=(-1)^{(k-1)/2}$ when $k$ is odd and it is zero otherwise. Therefore after letting $k=2j+1$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{k\pi}{2})}{k}=
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to show convergence is to calculate the sum explicitly.

The sum to be calculated is

$$s=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)}{k}$$

It is easy to see that this sum is equivalent to

$$t=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{2 k+1}$$

Consider now the expansion into a geometric series

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n x^{2 n}$$

Integrating the relation over x from 0 to 1 gives for the l.h.s

$$\text{lhs}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1} \, dx$$

and for the right hand side exactly the sum t.

The integral lhs can be evaluated easily by changing variables $x\to \tan (z)$ to give

$$\text{lhs}=\tan ^{-1}(1)$$

Hence the sum $s$ is equal to $\frac{\pi }{4}$